# Annabi Adam (AS) as a prophet of Allah SWT

Tags: quran, jannah, prophets

Assalamualaikum waramatullahi wabarakatuhu

I was having a conversation with a sheik one day so he mentioned that every prophet of Allah was send to a particular tribe or set of people
So I want to ask, was Annabi Adam (AS) sent to some people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different views regarding the time from which he was a prophet, depending on that the answer could be the angels ([2:30-33](https://legacy.quran.com/2/30-33)) or his family (his wife Eve and his children).